Excel subtract function
How to subtract the A1 - E1. So if the cell B1 to E1 is not blank, considered it as value 1 on each cell. So if you can see the image, the F1 is 6, because 10 (which is A1) - 4 (which is B1 to E1)




A
B
C
D
E
F




10
21-Mar
21-Mar
21-Mar
21-Mar
6



I need your help on what's the function on F1.

Just use COUNTBLANK and COUNTA to count blank and non-empty cells respectively
So put this in F1:
=A1 - COUNTA(B1:E1)

